# Unable to get members of Universal Distribution List using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, distribution-list

I am trying to write a script to list out all members of a "Universal Distribution List" using Powershell.  However I keep getting an empty result set back.

When I run the following command against a "Global Distribution List" it works fine and I can see who belongs to it.

```
dsquery group -name "SomeGroup" | dsget group -members -expand
```

However as I mentioned when I run this against a "Universal Distribution List" I get no results.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [quest AD cmdlets](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx).